# Same String Different Files regex does not work

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a couple of text files all in .gz format. Now I run this code in a pyspark script:

```
with gzip.open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read().decode('utf-8')
Func_that_does_regex(file_content)
```

The regular expression does not work (no errors but does not produce the correct output) and because the code is executed on a spark worker I have no good idea how to debug it. But if I decompress one file then manually copy paste the content Into a new text file (via leafpad) and gzip it again, the regular expresion works. If I print chunks of the string via the pyspark .take() methode both strings from the original and the the new file 'look' identical. What am I missing?

Python 3.5 and Spark 2.0.1

Comment: It's quite had to say if you not provide sample gz file...

Comment: Example gz file: [link](https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-40/segments/1474738659496.36/wet/CC-MAIN-20160924173739-00003-ip-10-143-35-109.ec2.internal.warc.wet.gz)

Comment: Do not run ".decode('utf-8')" after read.
Make sure your regex is in binary (eg: re.compile(b'myregex') ).

Comment: Test you Func_that_does_regex line-by-line in the spark shell.

Comment: Will be back to work after Christmas will give updates then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issued had to do with how different OS handle a new line in string. Before I only ever worked with in Linux created files, so \n in a regex was enough. The files I now got use \r\n for a new line though, hence my regex no longer worked!

\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows